# Python under Excel is slower. Why?

Tags: python, excel, datanitro

We are embedding Python inside our application. Our application has number of client interfaces, including the Excel and command line tool. At startup our aplication might read (depending on some parameters) large number of Python files. And here is the problem: we observe that application startup under Excel is slower than it is in command line tool. Numbers are not consistent and different for differnet users/boxes, but in some cases we observe it is up to 10 times slower and sometimes it is only 40%. Regardless it is a problem and I wanted to ask if anyone has any ideas why this could be. Application goes through exacty the same path in both cases (there are few irrelevant differences specific to Excel, but Python path is identical).

It *appears* (that what I can tell from cProfile report) that Python's open command runs significantly slower, but why - this is what I need to figure out.

Any help appreciated.

Thx.

P.S. Could someone from DataNitro shed some light on this? Do you observe the same behavior?

Comment: Can you send me an email with some more details?  In particular, how are you connecting to Excel?  I'm ben@datanitro.com.

Comment: How do you embed python? Read/write files? Which module do You use?

Comment: @akaRem Big picure: we are using Boost.Python. We have multiple Python modules with exported code and as also deploy some of the code in a form of Python extention modules whic hwe read during initialization of Boost.Python module